# Google Sheets filter out emails based only on the email domain

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I want to filter out all emails with a certain a domain (like @yahoo.com) from a google sheet email list, based on a list of email domains to filter out.

Let's say `Sheet1` looks like this (the list I want to filter):

```
tod     bose    tbose@sink.com  
william small   wsmall@sink.com 
Kafka   snail   ksnail@sink.com 
John    Bose    Jbose@sink.com  
Aug     Smith   asmith@yahoo.com
Aaron   Moog    amoog@googol.com
```

`Sheet2` looks like this (The exclusion filter criteria (I want to exclude these from the list on `Sheet1`)):

```
*@sink.com
*@yahoo.com
```

And `Sheet3` is using a standard Google Sheets filter like this:

`=filter(Sheet1!A1:C5, ISNA(match(Sheet1!C1:C5,Sheet2!C1:C11, 0)))`

And the filtered `Sheet3` (the filter has not worked) looks like this (this should show the resulting filtered list):

```
tod     bose    tbose@sink.com  
william small   wsmall@sink.com 
Kafka   snail   ksnail@sink.com 
John    Bose    Jbose@sink.com  
Aug     Smith   asmith@yahoo.com
Aaron   Moog    amoog@googol.com
```

How do I do this so it accounts for the wild card / or does something similar? How do I actually exclude all the emails based on the domain only?

I tried `=filter(Sheet1!A1:C5, search(Sheet2!C1:C5,Sheet1!C1:C5))` (and removed the `*`'s, but to no avail.

**Edit: I want to be left with just the googol email here, I want to filter the domains on Sheet2 out.

Here's the Googlesheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R08Srsal54hH42VgM7AJ2mAMYRKNOONLD2Yvzf3n__g/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(A1:C, REGEXMATCH(C1:C, ".*@sink.com|.*@yahoo.com"))
```

[image]

---

reverse:

```
=FILTER(A1:C, A1:A<>"", NOT(REGEXMATCH(C1:C, ".*@sink.com|.*@yahoo.com")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I want to be left with just the googol email here, I want to filter the domains on Sheet2 out. Can I reverse this with an exclamation mark somewhere? Also, the exclusion list might grow.

Comment: I tried this `=FILTER(A1:C, NOT(REGEXMATCH(C1:C, ".*@sink.com|.*@yahoo.com")))` But I get the error `Error
Circular dependency detected. To resolve with iterative calculation, see File > Spreadsheet Settings.`

Comment: @AgentZebra can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Oh wait, that error goes away when I try `=FILTER(Sheet1!A1:C, (NOT(REGEXMATCH(Sheet1!C1:C, ".*@sink.com|.*@yahoo.com"))))` but it does not exclude, I just get an empty sheet

Comment: Link to googlesheet added above. Thank you.

Comment: @AgentZebra see your Sheet5

Comment: Wow that's brilliant. Thank you. How did you know to add the `<>` and the pipe `|`? And why does it need those and the TEXTJOIN?

Comment: @AgentZebra `|` means OR in regex terms and `<>` is for excluding empty rows